# Making something move using a while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Why doesn't this work and how can I improve it to make it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        #container{
        posistion: relative;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        outline: 1px solid black;}
        #character{
        posistion: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        outline: 2px solid black;
        background-color: #FF6600;
        left: 0;
        </style>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
            <div id="character">
            </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                var character = getElementById('character');
                var container = getElementById('container');
                while (1 == 1){
                window.setTimeout(moveCharacter, 400);}

                function moveCharacter(){
                character ++;
                character.style.left = character + 'px';}
            </script>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` arranges for the function to be called at a particular time in the future. The call to `setTimeout()` returns immediately. It does not pause execution. You can use `setInterval()` to make something happen repeatedly with some interval between invocations.

Comment: This will lock up your machine because `while (1 == 1)` is an infinite loop which will eat all available cycles. _JavaScript_ has no _sleep_ style methods, perhaps you want to use a recursive `setTimeout` pattern instead.

Comment: while (1 == 1) is an infinite loop...

Answer (score 0):

With the `while (1 == 1)` you cause a blocking statement and no further code is executed. Try replacing

```
while (1 == 1) {
    window.setTimeout(moveCharacter, 400);}
```

with [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

```
window.setInterval(moveCharacter, 400);
```

Comment: Personally prefer a _setTimeout_ loop than _setInterval_, just in case you have a situation which can cause a cascade; `(function step() {moveCharacter(); window.setTimeout(step, 400);}());`

Comment: @PaulS. how would you break the loop this way? I mean, how do you simulate `clearInterval()`?

Comment: I squeezed that into a one-liner, for a full implementation you'd either set flags or keep track of indices which you can check against. It's not too hard, e.g. `function timeoutLoop(fn, delta) {function step() {if (step.cancelled) return; fn(); window.setTimeout(step, delta);} window.setTimeout(step, delta); return step;}` and cancel by `foo.cancelled = true;`

Comment: @PaulS. Alright. Anyway, I feel more readable using `setInterval()`rather than executing a function that calls itself with a timeout. Just a matter of preferences, I guess.

Comment: `setInterval` is a lot cleaner, I don't argue with that. Just the way it is spec'd, which means if the function takes longer to complete than the interval takes to start a second invocation, you have started a cascade failure.